# jQuery mobile/ ui simple import

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've never done jQuery Mobile before - having trouble getting this simple tabbed example to work.

Problem: tabs do not display - they stay as just divs and li's.

Can anyone point out my error? probably pretty simple.

I imported jQuery UI, mobile, and jquery (normal). So I thought I had it all down. Mobile and UI extend normal jQuery right? But trying to follow the instructions here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#default I was unable to even do that.

any pointers?

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
        <h1>My App</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Hello world</p>  

        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="tabs-1">
                <p>Tab #1</p>
            </div>

            <div id="tabs-2">
                <p>Tab #2</p>
            </div>

            <div id="tabs-3">
                <p>Tab #3</p>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not included the necessary javascripts and css for tabs.Change the `head` tag like this:

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
</script>

</head>
```